# How do I check if there is an update to a website with python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner to web scraping, and I was wondering how could I check if a website I'm currently scanning gets an update. I want to make a discord bot that retrieves information from my local school's website (I have permission). My only issue with this project is that I want to keep track of the announcements they have listed on their site, and once they post it, I want the discord bot to immediately post it on discord. I do not have any code I have written yet because I am a little stumped on how I should approach this. Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can apply a hash function to the text string content you get when you scrape the website, store the resulting hash, and when you scrap the website again apply a hash function again and compare the new hash vs the old, if the hash has changed then you know the content of the site has changed.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum

Comment: It may be possible to check the page's [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) for updates without downloading or hashing the page.